# Chained and Simultaneous Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I just ran into a JavaScript situation where I need to use Promises to handle some chained queries. I need to make 5 total database queries. I'm going to isolate each query into their own function, for simplicity, let's call these functions (A1, B1, B2, B3, and BB1). Here are some details:

- `BB1` is dependent on the results on `B1`.
- `B1`, `B2`, and `B3` are all dependent on the results of `A1`.

What I would like to do is once I have the results of `A1`, I would like to use Promises to kick off `B1`, `B2`, and `B3` simultaneously. Once those three functions return, then I would like to kick off `BB1`.

I attempted something like:

```
A1() {
  // Recieved results from A1 Query
  console.log("CHECK 1");
  Promise.all([
    B1(), B2(), B3(),
  ]).then(() => {
     console.log("CHECK 4");
    // Wrap everything up
  });
}

B1() {
  // Recieved results from B1 Query
  console.log("CHECK 2");
  Promise.all(
    BB1(),
  ).then(() => {
    return;
  });
}

BB1() {
  // Recieved results from BB1 Query
  console.log("CHECK 3");
  return;
}
```

But my console is logging: "Check 1", "Check 2", "Check 4", "Check 3".

I also tried:

```
A1() {
  // Recieved results from A1 Query
  console.log("CHECK 1");
  Promise.all([
    B1(), B2(), B3(),
  ]).then(() => {
     BB1();
  }).finally(() => {
     // Wrap everything up
  });
}
```

But that also yielded the same results. How can I kick off three simultaneous functions, then kick off a chained function, and then finally wrap everything up? I've only been able to find results on one or the other, but not combination of both...

Comment: You need to return the promises from the functions if you want the caller to use them. You're also calling `Promise.all()` on the result of `BB1`, but `BB1` doesn't return a promise or an array of promises.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that the above code, as written, is not valid JavaScript. You've not identified the context/environment in which you are running either. Part of the answer is likely to include async/await but you have not idenified if that is available in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

As an async function:

```
async combinedQuery(){
  let a1 = await A1()
  console.log("first query done")
  let [b1, b2, b3] = await Promise.all([B1(), B2(), B3()])
  console.log("second query batch done")
  let bb1 = await BB1()
  console.log("all queries done:" a1, b1, b2, b3, bb1)
}
```

Assuming A1, B1, B2, B3, and BB1 are async functions, or return promises.

Answer (score -1):

It would be something like this:

```
A1.then((a1) => {
  Promise.all([B1, B2, B3]).then(([b1, b2, b3]) => {
    BB1.then((bb1) => {
      console.log(a1, b1, b2, b3, bb1);
    })
  })
})
```

Where A1, B1... are promises, not functions.